# Use Lightroom catalog on windows and mac

Tags: lightroom, workflow

I have my photos saved on an external hard drive formatted in exFat (so I can read and write from mac and windows). I have my catalog also saved on this drive. Every time I open the catalog from windows the files are missing. I understand that mac and windows have different file systems but is there a way to get around that? I want to use my catalog on both systems without having to relocate my pictures every time.

Answer (score 2):

You can create smart preview for the photos. And work on both platform with those previews. When it come time to export them you should do it from the platform you import the photos. Or update the library for particular OS.

Answer (score 2):

Mac and PC use different file path naming schemes, so paths stored into the catalog from the Mac will be meaningless on the PC.

A possible workaround could be (untested) to use UNC (aka. network) paths. If you create a share on the photo location (eg. D:\photos) you can access them via \\localhost\photoshare. This should work the same on both systems.

You might need to activate the [loopback adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/appvirtualization/de-DE/a4e5c780-7920-49e0-908f-aee0987ad41b/how-to-install-microsoft-loopback-adapter-on-windows-10?forum=win10itpronetworking).